# Global Eval with return value ?

Tags: javascript, eval

After searching a while , I was hoping to find a solution for global eval with a return value.

- `eval` will run in the current scope
- `Function constructor` will execute in its own local scope with access to global scope
- `setTimeout` trick is an async operation
- `script injection` can not return value
- `window.execScript` also - can not return value

So my question is:

Is there any other technique which runs at the global scope and can return value ?

(example will be much appreciated).

Comment: http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make eval to run in global scope, instead of

```
eval(s)
```

just use

```
window.eval(s);
```

or

```
var e=eval; e(s);
```

or

```
[eval][0](s)
```

This surprisingly happens because Javascript is weird and has a special rule about `eval`: when you're using the original `eval` object directly to evaluate a string the evaluation happens in the current context.

If an "indirect eval" is used instead (i.e. you store `eval` in a variable and then use the variable, or even if you access `eval` using the `window` object) the evaluation happens in the global context.

You can check this in a Javascript console:

```
function foo() {
    eval("function square(x){ return x*x; }");
}

function bar() {
    window.eval("function square(x){ return x*x; }");
}

foo()

square(12) // <-- this gives an error; direct evaluation was used

bar()

square(12) // <-- this returns 144
```

So `window.eval(s)` is not the same as `eval(s)` even if `window.eval === eval`.

### PS

Note that `eval` has a special specific language rule for this to happen, but the same apparently strange behavior can also be observed in other cases for a different reason.

If you have an object `x` with a method defined `m` then

```
x.m()
```

is not the same as

```
var mm = x.m; mm();
```

because `this` in the first case will be bound to `x` during execution of the code in `m` while in the second case `this` will be the global object.

So also in this case `x.m()` is different from `mm()` even if `x.m === mm`.

For the same reason `x.m()` is not the same as `[x.m][0]()` because in the latter `this` will be bound to an array object during the execution of method code instead of being bound to `x`.

Comment: tnx ( so why did jquery didnt use it in their globaleval func ?)

Comment: @6502 Can you please elaborate on `[eval][0](s)` ? I assume it's like `window[eval]` but what is this `[0]` ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: In Javascript `[x]` is just a one-element array containing `x`, and `x[0]` instead takes the first element of an array. Therefore `[eval][0]` is just a funny way to say `eval` (it takes the first element of an 1-element array that contains `eval`) and because you're not using `eval` directly the evaluation takes place in global environment also in this case.

Comment: Again  - Thank you. I appreciate your help. didn't know that when i use array :---> _and because you're not using eval directly the evaluation takes place in global environment also in this case_

Comment: @RoyiNamir: I've added a line to the post-scriptum section in which there's an explanation of why `[...][0]()` is not the same as `...()` also for regular Javascript code.

Comment: @6502 I tried it with my own function and it didnt work : http://jsbin.com/iHIRAdI/4/edit

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40033/discussion-between-6502-and-royi-namir)

Comment: Please remove that edit, it's not the same strange behaviour. `eval` behaviour does not have anything to do with the `this` value, and it cannot be fixed by using `.call()` (but by assigning it to a variable with the right name).

Comment: Bergi: I think it's clearly stated that it's not the same strange behavior, but just that `x()` and `[x][0]()` are not the same thing also in other cases and for example you can have `foo.bar()` behaving differently from `bar()` even if `bar === foo.bar`. BTW you cannot "fix" the issue naming a variable `eval`: if it's a variable then it's still an indirect evaluation and it will happen in the global scope.